# How to get a string from .properties file and use it in the same .properties file

Tags: java, internationalization, properties-file

Is there a way to retrieve the value of a var in a .properties file and use is inside the same .properties file?

Insted of this (where I have to write manually the words 'Main Menu' in every line)

```
mainMenuTitle = Main Menu
NotBlank.menu.title = the field 'Main Menu' can't be null
Size.menu.title = the field 'Main Menu' must contains 10 characters
```

I want something like this (where I get automatically the value of the var 'mainMenuTitle')

```
mainMenuTitle = Main Menu     
NotBlank.menu.title = the field **mainMenuTitle** can't be null
Size.menu.title = the field **mainMenuTitle** must contains 10 characters
```

Comment: Can you give some bigger piece of code? I don't understand what you want exactly.

Comment: It is possible. But what you do then is to put additional information into the file; and in order to be "useful" ... you will also have to write code that **interprets** your property strings. Meaning: if you define that `**string**` should denote "variable names" ... then your code has to parse each property; and act accordingly! In other words: there is no built-in support for such things; but you can add it (but of course, such properties will only work with **your** code then).

Answer (score 0):

You can get both message separately and then make a replace to inject the title

```
   @Inject
  public MessageSource messageSource;


public static String getMessage(String messageKey1, String messageKey12) {
    String title =  messageSource.getMessage(messageKey1, arguments, locale);
    String message =  messageSource.getMessage(messageKey2, arguments, locale).replace("**mainMenuTitle**", title);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This May be what you want, its a bit old , but may work for your needs.
 [Enabling constant substitution in Property Values](http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/Java/archives/0612/mair/index.html)
You can substitute a constant anywhere in the property value, and even have more than one constant within a value, as in the following example:

`CONST_1 = shoes and ships
CONST_2 = sealing wax
SomeValue = {CONST_1} and {CONST_2}`

In this example, the "SomeValue" property evaluates to "shoes and ships and sealing wax."